# How to use field calculator to create a field based on another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have a field called `RTS` (Range,Township,Section(typically looks like `153320` with each two digits representing)). Would like to transpose to Township Range Section. Example from above would look like `331520`.

Is there any VB or Python that would work?

For labeling, I used the following, which worked by the way.

```
Function FindLabel ( [RTS] )
  FindLabel = mid([RTS],3,2) & mid([RTS],1,2) & mid([RTS],5,2)
End Function
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15038/how-to-use-arcpy-updatecursor-to-update-a-field?

Comment: But when you only want to transpose in the fieldcalculator you already have your code to put in. Just without the Function stuff... So probably i understand you wrong...

Comment: Python     !Name![-2:]+!Name![2:4]+ !Name![:2] providing it is a string

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. For example using the field-calculator.

1. Create your three new Fields (e.g. using Toolbox)
2. FieldCalculator (e.g. Python syntax)

   Field `Township`:

   ```
   = ['RTS'][2:3]
   ```

   Field `Range`:

   ```
   = ['RTS'][0:1]
   ```

   Field `Section`:

   ```
   = ['RTS'][4:5]
   ```

Alternatively the following arcpy-code should work:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(myTable)
for row in cursor:
    value = row.get_value('RTS')
    row.set_Value('Township', value[2:3])
    row.set_Value('Range', value[0:1])
    row.set_Value('Section', value[4:5])

    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

EDIT: If you only want to reorder your value use this:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(myTable)
for row in cursor:
    value = row.get_value('RTS')
    row.set_Value('RTS', value[2:3] + value[0:1] + value[4:5])

    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Actually I'm wanting to have a single field, just in a different order.  Transpose 153320 to 331520.  Thanks for chiming in BTW

Comment: @STucker see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Just modify what you have for your labeling a little bit, for calculating it should be: `mid( [RTS] ,3,2) + mid( [RTS] ,1,2) + mid( [RTS] ,5,2)`

Comment: I guess for performance it´s better to cache the value of `[RTS]` before using it. Thus you won´t hit the database three-times but only once.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have suggested I think field calculator is the way to go on this one. I would just create a new field called TRS using a similar expression to the one you created the labels with.